# How safe is it to store your passwords in web browsers?

Tags: passwords, web-browser, password-management

I read an article about marketing companies using a  method to steal email addresses and passwords from web browsers.
It is much more convenient to store passwords in browsers but I was wondering how safe it is to have passwords stored in the browser  or should we use a password manager application?

Comment: link to article?

Comment: There are a number of questions here on this very topic. some are in the "Related" section on the side --->